# slideToggle classed element one at a time

Tags: jquery, css

my html:

```
<div class="showOnReady">*content*</div>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".showOnReady").delay(3000).each(function () {
            $(this).slideToggle("slow");        
        });
});
```

The trouble is they all happen at the same time.  The delay works fine, they don't appear until 3 seconds after the page has loaded but I want them to slideToggle one after the other.

Comment: What do you mean by `they`? Are there many elements with class `showOnReady`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their `index` to increase the delay between each animation, for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".showOnReady").delay(3000).each(function (i) {
            var del = i*500;
            $(this).delay(del).slideToggle(500);        
        });
});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/DVBS7/)**

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just came to that conclusion myself only without the index, just using a variable :) thank you though!